# Slicing dataframe, but len is wrong

Tags: python, pandas

I am slicing a dataframe along its indices and selecting a response variable, but the result of len is not correct:

[In]

```
new_df = df.loc[:1000,'y']
len(new_df)
```

[Out]

```
972
```

Any thoughts?   I thought len should return 1000

Comment: Are you sure there were more than 972 rows to begin with?

Comment: @ami - the df has over 250,000 rows.

Comment: See answer then, which shows how this could happen. I strongly suggest you output the `.head()` of your df.

Answer (score 4):

[`.loc` selects rows by index label value](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) (or by boolean mask).

[`.iloc` selects rows by ordinal position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer).

So use

```
df.iloc[:1000]
```

to select the first 1000 rows (assuming `len(df) >= 1000`).

To select only the `y` column, use

```
df['y'].iloc[:1000]
```